# Get bandwidth usage of pre-signed URL in real time?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Is there any way to get real time bandwidth usage of a particular pre-signed URL?

I did some Google searches and it seemed not possible?

We need this because we want to release some pretty large data sets (over 300GB) to our members and it wouldn't be wise to not audit the bandwidth usage against potential download abuses.

Comment: Does CloudWatch metrics works? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/user-guide/configure-metrics.html

Comment: @FabioManzano Is this real time? Can we detect if a pre-sign URL is being abused and disable it when it reaches some bytes mark?

Answer (score 1):

For Amazon S3 access logging, enable S3 Server Access Logging. Make sure that you store the log files in different bucket. The output format looks somewhat like Apache log files so there are lots of tools that process the data. A simple Python script can do the job too.

After deciding how to process the log files, you then need to develop something that processes the access data and generates alerts / alarms. You may want to take a look at presigned URLs, signed cookies, etc. to better control access. With 300 GB datasets and apx $0.09 per GB data transfer, it won't take long for abuse to rack up some bills.

Here is a document link with all the details:

[Amazon S3 Server Access Logging](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ServerLogs.html)

Comment: Is this real time? We don't want to just know who abused the downloading after the bills rack up, but stop him when he's abusing it. Is this possible with s3 access logging?

Comment: Unfortunately, there is  no real time for logging in S3. The log entry won't be created until after an activity such as download. The log update time is measured in minutes. You would need to implement your own access control on your website or similar to control who can access your files.

Comment: I can but the issue is if the one I give access to abuse the download or not. Seems it's impossible to audit download in real time with s3.