# Granting tens of thousands of AWS accounts access to a bucket?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

We are a humble startup that mines data from the entire Internet and put them in an Amazon S3 bucket to share with the world. For now we have **2TB** of data and soon we may reach the **20TB** mark.

Our subscribers will be able to download all the data from the Amazon S3 bucket we have. We have to opt for **requester pays** for the bandwidth apparently unless we want to end up with some heart breaking S3 bills.

Pre-signed URL is not an option because it doesn't seem to [audit bandwidth usage in real time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52062937/get-bandwidth-usage-of-pre-signed-url-in-real-time), thus is vulnerable to download abuses.

After some research [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/example-walkthroughs-managing-access-example2.html) seems to be the way to grant different AWS accounts the needed permissions to access our bucket:

```
{
   "Version": "2012-10-17",
   "Statement": [
      {
         "Sid": "Permissions to foreign account 1",
         "Effect": "Allow",
         "Principal": {
            "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::ForeignAccount-ID-1:root"
         },
         "Action": [
            "s3:GetBucketLocation",
            "s3:ListBucket"
         ],
         "Resource": [
            "arn:aws:s3:::ourbucket"
         ]
      },
      {
         "Sid": "Permissions to foreign account 2",
         "Effect": "Allow",
         "Principal": {
            "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::ForeignAccount-ID-2:root"
         },
         "Action": [
            "s3:GetBucketLocation",
            "s3:ListBucket"
         ],
         "Resource": [
            "arn:aws:s3:::ourbucket"
         ]
      },
      {
         "Sid": "Permissions to foreign account 3",
         "Effect": "Allow",
         "Principal": {
            "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::ForeignAccount-ID-3:root"
         },
         "Action": [
            "s3:GetBucketLocation",
            "s3:ListBucket"
         ],
         "Resource": [
            "arn:aws:s3:::ourbucket"
         ]
      },

      ......

   ]
}
```

Wherein `ForeignAccount-ID-x` is the account ID e.g. 2222-2222-2222.

However the issue is, we may potentially have tens of thousands or even more subscribers to this bucket.

Is this the right and efficient way to add permissions for them to access this bucket?

Would it pose any performance difficulties to this bucket considering each request would go through this mountainous bucket policy?

Any better solutions for this problem?

Comment: I would use Cognito to authorize a user, then have some sort of "middle layer" -- like API Gateway and/or a Lambda that will execute the request and retrieve the data on behalf of an authenticated request.

Comment: Note that bucket policies are limited to 20 KB in size as described [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/access-policy-alternatives-guidelines.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your requirement for [Amazon S3 Requester Pays Buckets](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/RequesterPaysBuckets.html) is understandable, but leads to other limitations.

User will **need their own AWS account** to authenticate — it will not work with federated logins such as AWS Cognito. Also, pre-signed URLs aren't of benefit because they are generated from an AWS account too.

Bucket policies are limited to 20KB and ACLs are limited to 100 grants.

So, this approach seems unlikely to work.

Another option would be to create a mechanism where your system can ***push* content to another user's AWS account**. They would need to provide a destination bucket and some form of access (eg an IAM Role that can be assumed) and your application could copy files to their bucket. However, this could be difficult for regularly-published data.

Another option would be to **allow access to the content *only from within the same AWS Region***. Thus, users would be able to read and process the data in AWS using services such as Amazon EMR. They could write applications on EC2 that access the data in Amazon S3. They would be able to copy the data to their own buckets. The only thing they cannot do is access the data from outside AWS. This would eliminate Data Transfer costs. The data could even be provided in multiple regions to serve worldwide users.

A final option would be to [propose your dataset to the AWS Public Dataset Program](https://aws.amazon.com/opendata/), which will cover the cost of storage and data transfer for "publicly available high-value cloud-optimized datasets".

Comment: Regarding "allow access to the content only from within the same AWS Region", users would still need AWS accounts to access the data, correct? Since we can't make the data public, it would need to rely on the bucket policy for permissions, right?

Comment: Since the data would only be accessible to the AWS range of IP addresses, they would need a resource within AWS to access the data (which therefore needs an account), but they wouldn't use User Pays (which requires an account). So they don't _directly_ need an account, but they do need one _indirectly_. And, you'll avoid Data Transfer fees!

Comment: You mean the same AWS region? As we can't simply make the data public, we will audit access to the data, why and how they need an account indirectly? I'm not quite following you, sorry.

Comment: By limiting access only to IP addresses associated with EC2 services in the same region, there will be no Data Transfer costs (hence, you do not need Requester Pays). However, the data will then only be accessible from _within AWS_ (due to the IP address restrictions), so your customers would need an AWS account to be able to access the data. You could then use pre-signed URLs to grant access.

Comment: That's a great idea thank you! However it will limit our users base to that specific region. There will be a lot of users who would prefer other regions. Any idea please?

Comment: Replicate the data to a bucket in every region via S3 Cross-Region Replication. Users will connect to the local bucket, eg "mycompany-ap-southeast-2". Attach a bucket policy with the IP address range for that particular region.

Comment: Understood. Forgive me for asking so many questions. Allowing access from IP ranges of AWS doesn't seem the right way to me here? As it gives ALL users of that IP range access to our data. How can we audit access on a per user basis here?

Comment: Correct. You will still need some form of authentication. This is merely a method of avoiding Data Transfer charges. A common way of granting access is to have an application, users authenticate to login and then the application can provide [Pre-Signed URLs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ShareObjectPreSignedURL.html) to the objects. The users do _not_ have direct access to Amazon S3.