# Restricting access to an S3 bucket by AWS region?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

We have lots of Internet-crawled MySQL databases and image files (xx TBs) that need to be distributed to our users. To avoid potentially staggering data transfer bills, we only allow access to our data downloads from within the same region.

How can we enforce this in the S3 bucket policy? What we have come up with is something like this:

```
{
   "Version": "2012-10-17",
   "Statement": [
      {
         "Sid": "Same region access only",
         "Effect": "Allow",
         "Action": [
            "s3:GetBucketLocation",
            "s3:ListBucket"
         ],
         "Resource": [
            "arn:aws:s3:::ourbucket"
         ],
         "Condition": {
            "IpAddress": {
                "aws:SourceIp": ["18.208.0.0/13", "52.95.245.0/24", "54.196.0.0/15", ... ]
            }
        }
      },
   ]
}
```

Wherein the IP ranges come from here: https://ip-ranges.amazonaws.com/ip-ranges.json

However there are **too many** IP ranges in there for any specific AWS region, that it's a chore to add them up to our bucket policy, which is vulnerable to changes that we have to keep up in future.

Is there any better way to achieve this, such as this:

```
{
   "Version": "2012-10-17",
   "Statement": [
      {
         "Sid": "Permissions to foreign account 1",
         "Effect": "Allow",
         "Action": [
            "s3:GetBucketLocation",
            "s3:ListBucket"
         ],
         "Resource": [
            "arn:aws:s3:::ourbucket"
         ],
         "Condition": {
            "Source": {
                "aws:Region": ["us-east-1", "eu-central-1", ... ]
            }
        }
      },
   ]
}
```

Which would be very nice. Possible? Or is the IP ranges the only way to do this?

Comment: For your [use-case](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52142654/174777), you would only need the EC2 ranges for each region, eg `[r['ip_prefix'] for r in ranges['prefixes'] if r['region'] == 'us-east-1' and r['service']=='EC2']`

Comment: @JohnRotenstein but what if users want to download the data to their S3 or other services?

Comment: The only services they are likely to use to access the data is Amazon EC2 and Amazon EMR (which runs on EC2). However, I guess they could issue a `Copy` command to S3 to copy the data from your bucket to their bucket using the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/), so it would be worth adding the range for S3, too. Are there any other services you were expecting them to use to access your data in S3?

Answer (score -2):

Although S3 buckets are region specific, this only affects latency when accessing them. By default, when accessed from the public internet, outgoing data transfers are priced the same regardless of the original region. Transfers between S3 buckets are also free of charge.

If you have enabled features such as CRR, there are separate replication fees, but again you will not be additionally charged for transfers to the public internet.

Cross-region transfers are charged when you are moving data from S3 to any other Amazon service of yours in a different region.

All related data and details can be found [here](https://aws.amazon.com/s3/pricing/#Data_Transfer_Pricing).

If you feel that it the pricing details in the above page are not clear enough, you should open a support case with Amazon, and they should be able to provide you with a more detailed answer.